# crontab doesn't run js script

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

I open

```
crontab -e
```

Then I put:

```
* * * * * ~/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/app/packages/package1/test.js
```

I save the file, it immediatelly says that it installed the cron. So I expect it to run every minute.

```js
//test.js

var fs = require('fs')

let data = "data";

fs.writeFileSync("programming.txt", data);
```

Somehow, no `programming.txt` file gets created in the `/home/ec2-user/app/packages/package1`.

I can see the logs `sudo nano /var/log/cron` and no error at all.

I am hitting the wall somehow. What could be wrong ?

I am using Linux Fedora Radhat...

Comment: Can you try using an absolute path, e.g. `fs.writeFileSync("/home/ec2-user/app/packages/package1/programming.txt", data);`? Does it work when executed manually?

Comment: move into the directory first, plop `cd /home/ec2-user/app/packages/package1 &&` just after the timings

Comment: Thanks guys. It fixed it.